# How to require a node module from the renderer in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, require

How can I require a node module from the `renderer.js` file for my Electron app ?

I'm trying to access the `Store` object from the `sindresorhus/electron-store` package in my `renderer.js` file. That file is called by index.html like this :

```
<script src="renderer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I installed the package using npm (`npm install electron-store`) and when I add `const Store = require("electron-store");` in the renderer, it's not doing anything (the rest of the Javascript isn't loaded/ran).

Note that all my files are located at the root of the project, next to my `main.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of preload argument in webPreferences while creating the main BrowserWindow.

OR

Try using remote module of electron (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote)

OR

Access the module in main process, call the functions for the expected outcome and send back the result to renderer process using IPC.

Answer (score -1):

You probably found the solution already but while creating browser window set nodeIntegration to true. Worked for me with electron-store but it won't work with electron modules. Only nodeJS ones.

EDIT: Just wanna add to this that you should probably just create the electron-store in the main.js process. Especially if the values from the config are required in other renderer processes.
Because it will be easier to get the values from across the whole app. And this might be problematic on the first run if the user decides not to run the renderer process in which the store is created.

```js
window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        webPreferences: 
        {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't enable node integration in your renderer processes, as it is considered a vulnerability https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/security.md#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content

Comment: It´s fine to use node integration as long as you serve local resources